# Understanding Escape characters in Unicode LDML Date Format for extended ISO 8601

Tags: datetime, unicode, datepicker, sapui5, iso8601

While using  the following control https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.DatePicker.html#setValueFormat

> Supported format options are pattern-based on Unicode LDML Date Format
>   notation. http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/#Date_Field_Symbol_Table

```
 <DatePicker id="date" value="{/bound/value}" valueFormat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z" displayFormat="MMMM d, y"change="handleChange"/>
```

In the pattern, the T is escaped with ' on either side.

According to https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime, "T" appears literally in the string, to indicate the beginning of the time element, as specified in ISO 8601.

I am confused about the usage pattern for escaping the Z at the end.

Regardless of how I escape the Z with `'`

- on both sides `valueFormat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"`
- or only in the beginning, `valueFormat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z"`,

I still get the correct value.

What is the correct usage here? I would think `'Z'` would be more consistent with how `'T`' is being escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Z is not a placeholder like the T. It is a designation of the timezone. If you look in the file you linked it refers to the pattern TZD to represent the designation of the timezone. This may be +1:00 or +11:00 or it may be just Z for Zulu or UTC.

Hopefully that clears it up.

`valueFormat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSTZD"` is what you are looking for.

Comment: valueFormat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX" was the exact string that worked for me.